# WIndows 10 Ethernet Usage - High Java usage

Tags: windows-10, java

I just discovered Windows 10 has a built in bandwidth monitor and was surprised at what it was telling me. It is a good thing I don't have a bandwidth limit because `Java` has been busy.

[image]

Is there any way I can see what Windows is counting as 'Java.exe'? Has anyone experienced this before?

This is only the past month and I would like to figure out what's going on.

Comment: You will have to use a different tool to determine what is actually using your bandwidth

Comment: The only conclusion I can draw from this is that a Java run script is using a large amount of bandwidth. You wouldn't by any chance be running a java based application like hosting a minecraft sever would you?

Comment: @BennettYeo Nope. No mine craft, and nothing else that I know of!

Comment: In that case I would recommend uninstalling Java unless you need it for software development. If one of your other programs complains about a Java dependency it will help you pinpoint the application.